# Errors in plots seasonal arima using the astsa package

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to fit a seasonal arima model to holiday demand data using the aster package in R.

```
sarima(turkey.ts,0,1,1,0,1,1,52)
```

Normally this function gives 4 plots as part of the output. However, I receive the following error:

```
"Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :'x' and 'y' lengths differ".
```

When omitting the plots using the argument "details=FALSE" the output of the model shows, but the plots do not. However, I would also like to use the plots to validate my model. Anyone who knows how to resolve this problem when plotting?

The data concerns a weekly time series of holiday demand:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2012, 18) 
End = c(2014, 52) 
Frequency = 52
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem trying to fit a simple AR1 model (no seasonality). It does the first plot but seems to fall down on the ACF of the residuals. My only clue is maybe my time series is too short - but that doesn't look to be your case...

Answer (score 0):

S parameter should probably be equal to 12:

```
library(nutshell)
library(astsa)
data("turkey.price.ts")
sarima(turkey.price.ts,p=0,d=1,q=1,P=0,D=1,Q=1,S=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Katia. Thank you for your reply. The S parameter stands for seasonality. Since my data is on a weekly basis I thought the S parameter should be 52 instead of 12. Could you explain a bit more why this would not be the case. Thank you.

Comment: @RosanneBaars Well I do not have your data, so I cannot really say why it does not work in your case but if you look at the data that come from the nushell package  (turkey.price.ts) and they are clearly on monthly basis. You might want to include your own data into the question, then it will be easier to debug the problem. If the data is very large, you might want to include the output of str(your_data)